# child added and child changed firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

i'm making an app using ionic and firebase as its backend. i'm making use of child added and child changed to watch for two seperate events but it keeps firing 2 times for child added and about 8 times for child changed and checking firebase, i had just one child added and not two....here are the code snippets

1.

```
  new Firebase("https://popping-torch-3029.firebaseio.com/btr/users/acceptedBySender/myid/").on("child_added",function(data,prevchild){

    console.log('added just fired');

       //the console will log this 2 times

 });
```

2.

```
    new Firebase("https://popping-torch-3029.firebaseio.com/btr/users/posted/myid/").on("child_changed",function(data){

       console.log('changed just fired');

       //the console will log this 8 times

    });
```

Comment: There's too much code here for me to quickly figure out what's going on. But from looking at your database, all users have more than 2 child nodes. If you run the same query *without* ionic, do you get the same problem? If so, post a minimal reproduction of your problem without ionic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how a minimal reproduction is helpful and why it allows us to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i just edited it. Please take another look, maybe you'll identify the problem now.

Comment: Nope. There is no data at these URLs. Also note that `child_changed` will only fire if the data is changing, which means that there must be something actively changing it. It's likely that you're having another client running that changes it. But without seeing a minimal, complete reproduction of the problem, there's simply not enough information to help. Consider setting up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reprodudes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem now. it turns out it was the controller was reloading due to the fact that the controller was tied to multiple views. each time it loaded it created a new 'watcher'....i hope this is clear